# Creating wrapper for C++ dll functions which can be used for C# callbacks

Tags: c#, c++, dll, delegates, callback

I have a C++ class which does network communications, and wish to use it in a C# application. However I wish to be able to have delegates pointing to the functions so that they can be used as callbacks. Does this change anything about the way I need to export the C++ dll?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737018/how-to-call-net-c-code-from-a-native-c-dll) might help

Comment: Apologies if the question was not clear enough but what I want is for the C++ functions to be used as callbacks with delegates in the C# app, not the other way around. I don't know whether this requires any extra work when exporting the functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Export the functions you need to call from the DLL as C functions and provide some delegates wrapper thing in your C# code.